# Ошибка табуляции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать программирование ботов на платформе vk api, но столкнулся с проблемой. Сидел 2 часа, но так и не смог решить

```
    import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


def main():
    session = requests.Session()
    
    login, password = 'login', 'password'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return
   

    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
            if event.text == 'Работай':
                if event.from_user:
                    vk.messages.send( #Если написали в ЛС
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        message='какой-то текст'
                    )
              
                elif event.from_chat: #Если написали в беседе
                    vk.messages.send(
                        chat_id=event.chat_id,
                        message='какой-то текст'
                    )
```

```
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
                                                                           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы сидеть два часа, можно было бы вбить текст ошибки в поиск (ну или хотя бы в англо-русский словарь) и через две секунды получить решение. Замени табы на пробелы и будет щасте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя для отступов используются табы и пробелы в перемешку, загугли команду для твоего редактора что бы заменить табы на пробемы, большинство редакторов умеют.
В виме например :retab